# Should the connection opened by subprocess.Popen() in python, be closed

Tags: python, mysql, popen

I'm very new to python. I would like to know, when using `subprocess.Popen` do we need to close the connection or subprocess automatically closes the connection?

```
process = subprocess.Popen(["mysql", "-uroot", "-ppassword", "database"], 
           stdin = subprocess.PIPE, 
           stdout = subprocess.PIPE, 
           stderr = subprocess.PIPE) 
process_out, process_err = process.communicate(file("test.sql").read())
print process_out
```

Comment: Usually, the examples in the official documentation are complete. There the connection is not closed. So you do not need to close most probably.

Comment: unrelated: you could use `stdin=open('test.sql', 'rb', 0)` to redirect child's stdin from the file without loading the whole file into your Python process first.

Answer (score 3):

`process` is the object which represents the subprocess. With it, you can do everything you want, but at the end, after having processed all communication, you should `.wait()` for it in order not to have a zombie process for a too long time.

Only after `.wait()` the subprocess will be really gone from the view of the OS.

The said is valid if you handle the communication on your own. But if your circumstances allow you to use the `.communicate()` method and you do so, you don't have to call `.wait()`, as it does so for you.

Comment: [Popen.communicate()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) waits for the process to terminate.

Comment: This will deadlock when using stdout=PIPE and/or stderr=PIPE and the child process generates enough output to a pipe such that it blocks waiting for the OS pipe buffer to accept more data. Use communicate() to avoid that.

Comment: Of course. `.wait()` should occur after the communication has been done.

Answer (score 3):

`.communicate()` call closes all the pipes (if it is what you mean by "connection") and reaps the child process. You don't need to do anything after that.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

with open('test.sql', 'rb', 0) as input_file, \
     Popen([cmd] + args, stdin=input_file, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE) as p:
    output, errors = p.communicate()
if p.returncode != 0:
   raise Error
```